# Как проверить одинаковые ли значения определённого поля в словаре Python

Tags: python, словари, dict

Есть цикл (stickers_dict), который проходится по словарям. Нужно каким-то образом проверять, одинаковые ли значения у всех элементов словаря у определённых полей. Если да, то выполнять условие.
Прилагаю примеры: 1) словаря, который проходит проверку, 2) словаря, который не проходит проверку:

```
    {
        0: {'stickerId': 2154, 'slot': '1', 'codename': 'krakow2017_signature_gla1ve', 'name': 'gla1ve | Krakow 2017'},
        1: {'stickerId': 2154, 'slot': '1', 'codename': 'krakow2017_signature_gla1ve', 'name': 'gla1ve | Krakow 2017'},
        2: {'stickerId': 2154, 'slot': '1', 'codename': 'krakow2017_signature_gla1ve', 'name': 'gla1ve | Krakow 2017'},
        3: {'stickerId': 2154, 'slot': '1', 'codename': 'krakow2017_signature_gla1ve', 'name': 'gla1ve | Krakow 2017'}
    }


    {
        0: {'stickerId': 2154, 'slot': '1', 'codename': 'krakow2017_signature_gla1ve', 'name': 'gla1ve | Krakow 2017'},
        1: {'stickerId': 2208, 'slot': '3', 'codename': 'krakow2017_signature_edward', 'name': 'Edward | Krakow 2017'},
        2: {'stickerId': 101, 'slot': '4', 'codename': 'comm01_backstab', 'name': 'Backstab'},
        3: {'stickerId': 2208, 'slot': '3', 'codename': 'krakow2017_signature_edward', 'name': 'Edward | Krakow 2017'}
    }
```

Проверять можно по любому полю, например, stickerId, которое имеет путь `stickers_dict[stickers_item]['stickerId']`

Comment: а проверять надо все поля или только определённые?

Comment: @Zhihar будет достаточно одного поля. Например, stickerId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если проверка по одному полю, есть смысл функции проверки:

```
def check_by_key(my_dict, key_check):
    values = []

    for el in my_dict.values():
        values.append(el[key_check])
        
        if len(set(values) > 1:
            return False

    return True
```

Для `my_dict`:

```
my_dict = {
        0: {'stickerId': 2154, 'slot': '1', 'codename': 'krakow2017_signature_gla1ve', 'name': 'gla1ve | Krakow 2017'},
        1: {'stickerId': 2154, 'slot': '2', 'codename': 'krakow2017_signature_gla1ve', 'name': 'gla1ve | Krakow 2017'},
        2: {'stickerId': 2154, 'slot': '3', 'codename': 'krakow2017_signature_gla1ve', 'name': 'gla1ve | Krakow 2017'},
        3: {'stickerId': 2154, 'slot': '4', 'codename': 'krakow2017_signature_gla1ve', 'name': 'gla1ve | Krakow 2017'}
    }
```

результат с разным `key_check`:

```
>>> check_by_key(my_dict, 'stickerId')
True
>>> check_by_key(my_dict, 'codename')
True
>>> check_by_key(my_dict, 'slot')
False
```

Answer (score 1):

можно воспользоваться волшебной функцией `str()`:

```
arr1 = {
    0: {'stickerId': 2154, 'slot': '1', 'codename': 'krakow2017_signature_gla1ve', 'name': 'gla1ve | Krakow 2017'},
    1: {'stickerId': 2154, 'slot': '1', 'codename': 'krakow2017_signature_gla1ve', 'name': 'gla1ve | Krakow 2017'},
    2: {'stickerId': 2154, 'slot': '1', 'codename': 'krakow2017_signature_gla1ve', 'name': 'gla1ve | Krakow 2017'},
    3: {'stickerId': 2154, 'slot': '1', 'codename': 'krakow2017_signature_gla1ve', 'name': 'gla1ve | Krakow 2017'}
}

arr2 = {
    0: {'stickerId': 2154, 'slot': '1', 'codename': 'krakow2017_signature_gla1ve', 'name': 'gla1ve | Krakow 2017'},
    1: {'stickerId': 2208, 'slot': '3', 'codename': 'krakow2017_signature_edward', 'name': 'Edward | Krakow 2017'},
    2: {'stickerId': 101, 'slot': '4', 'codename': 'comm01_backstab', 'name': 'Backstab'},
    3: {'stickerId': 2208, 'slot': '3', 'codename': 'krakow2017_signature_edward', 'name': 'Edward | Krakow 2017'}
}

print(len({str(obj) for obj in arr1.values()}) == 1) # True

print(len({str(obj) for obj in arr2.values()}) == 1) # False
```

для более короткой записи можно и так:

```
print(len({str(arr1[key]) for key in arr1}) == 1)
```

Comment: не до конца понимаю как это использовать. То есть мне нужно убрать print и добавить эту строку как условие для if? А как тогда указать по какому ключу необходима проверка?

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import reduce


x = {
        0: {'stickerId': 2154, 'slot': '1', 'codename': 'krakow2017_signature_gla1ve', 'name': 'gla1ve | Krakow 2017'},
        1: {'stickerId': 2154, 'slot': '1', 'codename': 'krakow2017_signature_gla1ve', 'name': 'gla1ve | Krakow 2017'},
        2: {'stickerId': 2154, 'slot': '1', 'codename': 'krakow2017_signature_gla1ve', 'name': 'gla1ve | Krakow 2017'},
        3: {'stickerId': 2154, 'slot': '1', 'codename': 'krakow2017_signature_gla1ve', 'name': 'gla1ve | Krakow 2017'}
    }


y = {
        0: {'stickerId': 2154, 'slot': '1', 'codename': 'krakow2017_signature_gla1ve', 'name': 'gla1ve | Krakow 2017'},
        1: {'stickerId': 2208, 'slot': '3', 'codename': 'krakow2017_signature_edward', 'name': 'Edward | Krakow 2017'},
        2: {'stickerId': 101, 'slot': '4', 'codename': 'comm01_backstab', 'name': 'Backstab'},
        3: {'stickerId': 2208, 'slot': '3', 'codename': 'krakow2017_signature_edward', 'name': 'Edward | Krakow 2017'}
    }

print(reduce(lambda a, b: b if x[a] == x[b] else False, x.keys()) is not False)    # True
print(reduce(lambda a, b: b if y[a] == y[b] else False, y.keys()) is not False)    # False
```